# Exportar informaçõs do MYSQL para JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Desculpem a ignorância, não entendo nada de JSON.

Tenho um site com base de dados em MYSQL que o cliente precise que exporte para JSON para integrar com um app.

Podem me dar uma luz de onde começar?

Ex: tabela com informações: nome, email, id

Obrigado!

Comment: Pode começar com a função [json_encode\(\)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) se tiver mais detalhes edite a pergunta.

Comment: você quer pegar os dados cia banco e utilizando o PHP para converter os dados para json?

Comment: Cara você deve fazer um select no banco de dados, com PHP por exemplo, e este retorno vc manda via json_encode()... ae vc pode trabalhar    ele no app ou javascript..

Comment: Eu faria tipo um select para trazer os resultados como se fosse fazer com um echo, mas ao invés do echo usa json_enconde?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para criarmos o conteúdo de um arquivo `JSON`, primeiramente criamos um `array`:

```
$meus_dados = array();
```

Após termos um `array` criado devemos popular esse `array`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $meus_dados[$i]['nome'] = "nome".($i + 1);
    $meus_dados[$i]['email'] = "email".($i + 1);
    $meus_dados[$i]['id'] = "id".($i + 1);
}
```

Agora que já temos nosso `array` populado, temos que usar a função `json_encode` para gerarmos um `JSON` desse `array`:

```
echo json_encode($meus_dados);
```

**Resultado**

> [{"nome":"nome1","email":"email1","id":"id1"},
>   {"nome":"nome2","email":"email2","id":"id2"},
>   {"nome":"nome3","email":"email3","id":"id3"}]

Comment: antes do $meus_dados = array(); eu faço a conexão normal com o banco de dados? ($conecta = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);)

Comment: Sim, eu coloquei o exemplo dessa forma para deixar genérico, mas a sua consulta com `mysqli` já irá retornar um `array`, você pode dar um `json_encode` direto.

Comment: acho que deu certo, mas uma dúvida, esse $i < 3, limita para 3 resultados? se sim, da pra deixar sem limite, para trazer tudo?

Comment: Na verdade, ele esta limitando a quantidade de vezes que vamos popular o nosso `array`. você esta populando o seu `array` manualmente ou esta utilizando o `array` que o `mysqli` retorna para você?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode trabalhar da seguinte forma utilizando o PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($stmt){
    echo json_encode(["status"=>true,"msg"=>"Json enviado com sucesso!","data"=>$stmt]);exit;
}else{
    echo json_encode(["status"=>false,"msg"=>"Ocorreu um erro"]);exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O JSON (http://json.org/) é um formato de dados. Ele facilita a troca de dados entre diferentes sistemas, pois é simples de gerar e recuperar. Para o seu caso, você precisa gerar uma saída em JSON para que seja lida pelo sistema.

Recupere os dados da mesma maneira que faria para qualquer aplicação. A diferença será na saída (ou exibição em tela), que terá o formato `application/json`. Do modo mais simples possível:

```
$data = mysql_query('select * from table'); // aplique o seu metodo de recuperacao de dados
header('Content-type: application/json'); // cabecalho para o navegador saber que estah retornando um json
echo json_encode($data); // json_encode transforma qualquer tipo de objeto no formato json
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver usando PDO pode ficar bem elegante seu retorno:

```
public function getCliente ( $idcliente ){
        require_once "class.connection.php";
        require_once "../model/class.cliente.php";
        $retorno = array();
        $this->connection = new connection();

        try{
            $query = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE CD_CLIENTE = :cliente";
            $stmt = $this->connection->prepare( $query );
            $stmt->bindValue( ":cliente", $idcliente, PDO::PARAM_INT );
            $stmt->execute();

            if( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
                $retorno = array(
                   "id"    =>  $row['CD_CLIENTE'] ,
                   "nome"  =>  $row['NM_CLIENTE'] ,
                   "email" =>  $row['DS_EMAIL']
                )
            }

            $this->connection = null;
        }catch (PDOException $ex){
            echo "Erro: ".$ex->getMessage();
        }
        echo json_encode(array("cliente" => $retorno));
    }
```

O retorno será mais ou menos assim:

```
{
  "cliente" : [{
              "id"    : "1",
              "nome"  : "Leandro",
              "email" : "leandro@email.com"
              }]
}
```

Comment: Você não entendeu?